# django form only requesting GET

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm new to Django and I was working user registration and i wanted to custom registration form instead of Django's default user form but in my custom user registration form, Everytime when I tried to register the form only sends GET request and it doesn't register it just reloads the page. I tried to look different resources but I still could not figure it out.

Here is my code

views

```
    import email
    from http import client
    from multiprocessing import context
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
    from client.forms import Registerationform
    
    
    
    # Create your views here.
    def register(request):
        context = {}

        if request.method == 'POST':
           
            form = Registerationform(request.POST)
           
            if form. is_valid():
              
                form.save()
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                client = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
                login(request, client)
                return redirect('product')
            else:
           
                context['registeration_form']  = form
        else:
           
            form = Registerationform()    
            context['registeration_form'] = form
        return render(request, 'client/register.html', context)
```

templates register.html

```
    {% extends 'main.html' %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
    <div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>  
                    {% for field in registeration_form %}            
                           <p>                      
                               {{field.label_tag}}                            
                               {{field}}
    
                            </p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn -outline-info" type="submit">
                </div>
    
            </form>
            <div class="norder-top pt-3">
                <small class="text-muted">
                    Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign in</a>
                </small>
            </div>
    </div>
    <style>
    .content-section {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    
    input {
        opacity: 0.3;
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 80%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        box-shadow: none;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        background-color: #5d5d5d;
        transition: 1s;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
    }
    </style>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Show us `views` (edit you question with it), because there we can see important code.

Comment: here is my view ☝

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `action` attribute on `<form>`

```
<form action="{% url 'url_name_for_the_view' %}" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}

.
.
.
</form>
```

Comment: you can just use `action="{{ request.path }}"` to get directly the current url.

Comment: Shouldn't we actually manage url redirecting in `views` directly?

Comment: yes that's how I did it and it has no effect on this.